# How to get a list of users from azure graph API

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a list of users from azure ad using graph api. I have got the access token by using the below query:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-Id>/oauth2/token
```

[image]

I got below response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1559555742",
    "not_before": "1559551842",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEQ29NcGpKWHJ4VHE5Vkc5dGUtN0ZYUy1XcWZRa2RmUmVnSVJfWE4yLXdYSFZwLXJKdlltcWVzTzAwSmd1V2dJOVVQUVBWbldScjhtZjM1SHhXblhFcWhIMVlWY1Y2NlYS00ZTE1LTQ0NWEtOTM0Ni02YTBhOGQxN2UxOTYvIiwib2lkIjoiYzE0YzFlYmEtYzExMS00ZmMxLTllYjAtYTJmNGMwNjg4MDEyIiwic3ViIjoiYzE0YzFlYmEtYzExMS00ZmMxLTllYjAtYTJkKgCbMg5jElY2I83cKpRos6Jti3SUYIVTYiyF__gMsKzCQWgRZFUWnTi7syaypCrPEExPw_OMRJMNMOrYixTBZjwUi0H6ThGNxQOMt5mXhzvlVYRMdyChdmv4r2-JK-LX9yjBN8BWG78e3FYhWQCRERh5H3zNpdX1ln79QY38mhn-XJViA2vX-VCYqZhoUo-c_iR-_HZ3CLCHxRxgRHtT_oGXuX1Kegxo3F6FsuQ2Vj1WT5VjCRGCi71pY_lU_EROzkLdefS84fur4jBawvd1ccCf8u9U0kYy3xu0m02wNxKPe2Weg"
}
```

Once I have the token, I am referring to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) and using below url to get the user list:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

and also passing the token in header but getting below error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f03e6cc4-1888-406d-9ee4-2558b96e7fb4",
            "date": "2019-06-03T09:22:30"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I am doing this from postman as of now but later have to do it from python script. Can anyone please suggest what is wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are trying to fetch `user list` using Microsoft Graph. To do that see the following steps:

**Azure portal Permission:**

Go to your Azure portal tenant and set below permission on "API permissions" menu. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**See the Application Permission Like below:**

[image]

**Do the same for dedicated permission. See the dedicated permission below**

[image]

**Your Permission should look like below:**

[image]

**Request for Token:**

Send request to your token endpoint with your credentials. Like below:

[image]

**Decode Token and Check Permission:**

Once you get your token make sure on [`https://jwt.io/`](https://%60https://jwt.io/%60) that your token contains required permission like below:

[image]

**Request For User List**

In this stage add your token on `Type` as `bearer token`, paste your token on Token text box and click send:

[image]

**Get The Users List:**

You will get your User List as specified in below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: When I click on `Add a permission` and select `Microsoft Graph`, it ask me for `Delegated Permissions` or `Application Permissions`. What should I choose.?

Comment: Application Permissions

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer please check the screen shot

Comment: The token which I was using has expired now. I am submitting the request to generate the token again but its giving me same token. Very strange. Do you have any idea on how to generate the new token again

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Just wanted to check if I want to create user, I need to set User.ReadWrite.All permission in ad app.?

Comment: Yeah `User.ReadWrite.All `

Comment: No I have set User.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All but getting `Insufficient privileges` error

Comment: Just decode your token on jwt and let me know the permission is available

Comment: Can you please let me know on how to decode it, I am very new to this.

Comment: Also can you comment here as I have created another question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426417/how-to-create-a-user-using-azure-graph-api Thanks

Comment: I got it working too. I was using application permission but I had to use delegated permissions

Comment: I have similar setup in postman and getting the users in response too but not all the users from the Org. Any idea why it is not returning all the users?

Comment: Could you please post another question so that it can be checked there.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps as below.

1.In your AD App -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> select `Microsoft Graph` -> `Application permissions` -> `User.Read.All` -> click `Add permissions` -> click `Grant admin consent for xxx`

2.Use the client credentials flow to get the access token.

[image]

3.Then you could use the token returned by step 2 to call the MS graph api, it should work.

[image]

Comment: I am also getting the token using the client credential flow. I have attached a screenshot of it in the question. Please let me know how do I use that token to further call the MS graph api.?

Comment: @SAndrew See the `step 1` in my reply, did you grant the `User.Read.All` permission for your ad app?

Comment: Can you explain the step 3. Where did you added that token. I am bit new to this software Postman

Comment: @SAndrew See the screenshot in step 3, Click `Authorization` -> select `Bearer Token` -> paste your token -> `Send`, no need to write the `Authorization` manually in the header.

Comment: When I click on `Add a permission` and select `Microsoft Graph`, it ask me for `Delegated Permissions` or `Application Permissions`. What should I choose.?

Comment: And lets say if I want to create and delete user as well, should I select `User.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: @SAndrew 1. we use `client credentials flow` here, so we need to select `Application permission`, 2. yes, you could find the permissions in the doc, from least to most, https://i.stack.imgur.com/m24u3.png

Comment: Thank you. I am getting `Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.`. How do I renew it. ?

Comment: @SAndrew Do step 2 again to request a new token.

Comment: Yes I did that but its giving me same token again and same error that `Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.`

Comment: @SAndrew Try to generate a new secret for your AD App, then use the new one.

Comment: Very strange that its giving the same token even after using the new secret.