# How to create a user using azure graph api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a user using `azure graph` API. For this, I have got the token response as below:

[image]

Once I have the token, I have added this as bearer token in Authorization for the below url:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

and posting the below json data:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Andrew",
  "mailNickname": "SanAndrew",
  "userPrincipalName": "andrew.san204@gmail.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

But getting below error:

```
{
    " error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c06079d2-ff6b-4e5b-b34d-704f16bc312f",
            "date": "2019-06-03T11:20:20"
        }
    }
}
```

although I have all the permissions as shown below:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for the error is that you are trying to create a user with gmail.com domain. The domain needs to be one of the verified domains in your AAD tenant.

If you want to add a gmail.com user anyway, you need to send an invitation through the invitations endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Comment: Can you point me to invitation endpoint. I am not able to find it?

Comment: Edited post with the link